# Some files formats and one program icon in start menu and taskbar show a blank document icon

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons

Since two days ago my Windows 10 1803 started showing some files with a blank document icon, specifically ISO files show that instead of the default blank document with a CD on top of it.

Since the same moment also Adobe Reader icon shows as a blank document icon both in start menu and taskbar while the shortcut on desktop shows the normal red icon.

[image: Example]

I already reset icon and thumbnail cache, cleaned the previews from the windows cleanup utility, ran sfc /scannow, ran dism /restorehealth, reinstalled AMD graphics card drivers but I couldn't manage to solve the problem.

What should I do now?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my very bad English.